# Jenkins-Git Continuous Delivery

Tags: git, jenkins

I am wondering if there is a way to setup such process using Jenkins and Git related to the same branch:

1. Developer commit a change that get pushed to Repo and built by Jenkins (easy no problem).
2. Developer commit a change that makes a Jira ticket complete, so the feature is fully implemented, Jenkins does everything at step 1 and also
   deploys the new executable in test.

So the question is mainly if using Jenkins I can intercept some special commit message or something like that from the repository to implement a different path?

Comment: Branch in 1 is different to branch in 2?

Comment: I edited the question to add your comment.